# Call a function in a Postman request

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I need to call a function that returns the current date.
I have to call this function in an object (contained in the body of my query). This object has a property whose value is the current date.

I wrote the function code as follows in the "pre-request scripts" of a POST request:

```
function currentDate() {
    let currentDate = new Date();
    return formatDate(currentDate);
};

function formatDate(date) {
    return [date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate()].map(n => n < 10 ? `0${n}` : `${n}`).join('-');
};
```

Here is the property of the object in the body of my request:

[image]

Here is the error I get in console:

[image]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set an environment variable with the current date at the end of the pre-request script:

```
pm.environment.set("currentDate", currentDate());
```

Then use that in your request body:

```
"start": "{{currentDate}}"
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?